# Can I double integrate a function through r and theta instead of x and y?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Let's suppose a function $z=f(x, y)$ which has linear relationship with the distance from origin. For example we have a function $z=f(x, y)=max(-a \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+b,0)$, where $a,b>0$. And we're calculating it's double integral $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, y) \,dx \,dy$. Since the function involves max function, it would be easier to integrate it in polar coordinate form. So I'm wondering will the above double integral equals to $\int_{0}^{\frac{b}{a}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} -ar+b \,d\theta\ r \,dr$? Cause if both of them equals to the other, integrating through polar coordinate is definite integration compare to indefinite integration, which is way easier.

Comment: You forgot an $r$. $dxdy=r dr d\theta$

Comment: @Andrei Why I need to times r one more time? Shouldn't $\,d\theta\,dr$ equivalent to $\,dx\,dy$ just looping through the plane in different way.

Comment: When you change variables, you need to use the Jacobian. See for example https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/changeofvariables.aspx For polar coordinates the Jacobian is $r$, as seen at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation If you think that $x$ and $y$ have dimensions of length, $dxdy$ is area. $r$ is length, but $d\theta$ is angle. To transform to length you need $r d\theta$. But this is just a hand vawing argument. The wikipedia link contains the exact derivation.

Comment: @AndrewWolphoe integrating with respect to polar coordinates does go through the whole plane (that's why it's legitimate), but you have to multiply by a factor of $r$ because otherwise, some regions of space are given more "priority" than others. For the same small change in angle $\Delta\theta$, consider two regions subtending $\Delta\theta$ at the origin, one closer to the origin and one further away. Clearly, the one further away has larger area (larger by a factor of $r$), so in order for this area to be taken into account proportionately, you must consider $r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: But he does have the factor $\ r\ $. He's just written $\ rdrd\theta\ $ as $ d\theta\,rdr\ $ instead.  At least he did so in his original question.  I presume the omission of $\ r\ $ in his followup comment was just a typo. So the answer to his comment is no, he *doesn't* need *another* factor of $\ r\ $.

Comment: @lonza leggiera I fixed it after reading through their comments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up.  I should have thought to check the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** The two integrals do equal, and are both definite as the bounds of the integration are given.

**Long Answer:**  If we take your function to be,
$$z=f(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
b-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2},  & \text{for}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le\frac{b}{a} \\
0, & \text{for}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{b}{a}
\end{cases}=g(r,\theta)=
\begin{cases}
b-a r,  & \text{for }r\le\frac{b}{a} \\
0, & \text{for }r\ge\frac{b}{a}
\end{cases}$$

Which 'breaks' you function into two regions, hence the integral can also be broken in to two regions.
And if we take the

Then your integral, in x and y is
$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, y) \,dx \,dy=
\iint_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le\frac{b}{a}} b-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \,dx\,dy+
\iint_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{b}{a}} 0 \,dx\,dy
$$
or in polars
$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, y) \,dx \,dy=
\iint_{r\le\frac{b}{a}} b-ar \,dr\,rd\theta+
\iint_{r\ge\frac{b}{a}} 0 \,dr\,rd\theta$$

and as the integral of zero across any region is zero, thus the integral of zero disappear. Hence
$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, y) \,dx \,dy=
\int_{0}^{\frac{b}{a}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} -ar+b \,d\theta \,rdr$$
Hopfully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're quite right.  Changing to polar coordinates does simplify the problem considerably, and I believe the expression you've obtained for the integral in polar coordinates is correct.